# A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 404. Description: Not Found

Tags: python

I have built a bot which I want to deploy on GCP. However, I get this kind of error when running the script on GCP. The error is like this.

> A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 404. Description: Not Found.

```
# Getting the API KEY
with open(file = 'API_KEY.txt') as txt_file:
    API_KEY = txt_file.read()

# Instantiating the bot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token = API_KEY)
```

This is a part from the script. The script is run on a local machine successfully without throwing any error, however, as soon as I try to run the same script it throws the error.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Where you able to fix this?